# How can i call a function inside another Component with React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component (Navigation.js) which imports another component (Dialog.js). I want that if I react to a click event, call a function in the dialog component (handleClickOpen ()). But I don't know how to do that. So what i have to do ?

Navigation.js

```
 export default function SimpleBottomNavigation() {

 return (
<BottomNavigation
  value={value}
  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  showLabels
  className={classes.root}
  >
  <BottomNavigationAction
    label="Home"
    onClick={'HERE I WANT TO CALL THE FUNCTION IN THE DIALOG COMPONENT'}
    icon={<RestoreIcon />}
  />
  <BottomNavigationAction label="Neuer Plan" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />
  <BottomNavigationAction label="Azubis" icon={<LocationOnIcon />} />
 </BottomNavigation>
  );
}
```

Dialog.js

```
export default function CustomizedDialogs() {
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

*/THIS FUNCTION I WANT TO CALL FROM NAVIGATION.JS */
const handleClickOpen = () => {
  setOpen(true);
};

 [...]

return (
<div>
  <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
    Open dialog
  </Button>
  <Dialog
    onClose={handleClose}
    aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
    open={open}
  >
    <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
      Modal title
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent dividers>
      
  </Dialog>
</div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Can I have your full component code ?

Comment: We can't tell where in the tree each of those components are - you can probably pass that method you want to call down via a prop.

Comment: I can't see CustomizedDialogs component  in SimpleBottomNavigation component. If you are going to use it in SimpleBottomNavigation component, you can keep state values in parent component(it's SimpleBottomNavigation in your case) and pass with in props in children(CustomizedDialogs component). If you don't want to use this approach, you can look at Redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a aimple way to use child's functions, with functional components it's `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle`, along those lines:

Navigation (parent)

```
function Navigation() {

    const dialogRef = useRef();

    return(
        <button onClick={() => dialogRef.current.handleClickOpen()}>
            Click me!
        </button>
    );
}
```

Dialog (child)

```
const Dialog = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        const handleClickOpen = () => {
            //your implementation
        };
    });

    return (...);
});

If I over-simplified, please let me know :)
```